# GROUP BY a number of DAY in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query

```
    SELECT  dbo.f_DateWithoutHour (0,DATEADD (DAY, 3, TheDate)) AS Date
    FROM (
        SELECT TheDate 
        FROM xxxxxxx.dbo.dim_date (NOLOCK)
        WHERE  TheDate >= '2019-02-09 00:00:00' AND TheDate < '2019-04-07 00:00:00'
    ) AS dim_date
    GROUP BY dbo.f_DateWithoutHour (0,DATEADD (DAY,  3, dim_date.TheDate))
    ORDER BY Date
```

which return this

[image: Result Set]

But the thing is that i want to GROUP BY every 3 days so i get in return

```
       DATE
2019-02-12 00:00:00.000
2019-02-15 00:00:00.000
2019-02-18 00:00:00.000
2019-02-21 00:00:00.000
2019-02-24 00:00:00.000
          .
          .
```

Thanks

Comment: What does `f_DateWithoutHour` do? If it is nothing more complex than `CONVERT(date` why don't you just do that instead and do away with an expensive scalar UDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your WHERE clause: `AND DATEDIFF(DAY,'2019-02-09',TheDate) % 3 = 0`

This will evaluate the number of days between your initial date and the current value of TheDate. The modulus (%) operator will return 0 for every 3 days in the timeline. Note that performance may take a hit evaluating this expression for every row, depending on the number of members in the dimension.

Comment: Your answer works fine with 3 ! But i've tried with 4 and the last row of my set is `2019-04-09 00:00:00.000` even if in the where close it's limited to `2019-04-07 00:00:00.000` so it should stop to `2019-04-05 00:00:00.000`

Comment: @MatthieuRGX According to my math, with an interval of 4, it should stop at 2019-04-06, not 2019-04-05. If you want to handle more than 3-day intervals, though, you should include more examples and edge cases (including what happens when the difference in days is *exactly* divisible by 3 / 4 / etc). Your question only mentions 3 days and also doesn't explain whether a boundary should be included.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the need for the function, or the group by, or even the dimension table. Are there other `WHERE` clauses you're not telling us about? Otherwise this is just a dynamic generation of a list of dates:

```
DECLARE 
  @startDate date    = '20190219',
  @endDate   date    = '20190407',
  @interval  tinyint = 3;

;WITH n(n) AS 
(
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM n 
    WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY,@startDate,@endDate)/@interval
)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, @interval*n, @startDate)
  FROM n;
```

With an interval of 3, I get:

```
2019-02-12
2019-02-15
2019-02-18
2019-02-21
2019-02-24
2019-02-27
2019-03-02
2019-03-05
2019-03-08
2019-03-11
2019-03-14
2019-03-17
2019-03-20
2019-03-23
2019-03-26
2019-03-29
2019-04-01
2019-04-04
2019-04-07
```

With an interval of 4, same date range, I get:

```
2019-02-13
2019-02-17
2019-02-21
2019-02-25
2019-03-01
2019-03-05
2019-03-09
2019-03-13
2019-03-17
2019-03-21
2019-03-25
2019-03-29
2019-04-02
2019-04-06
```

If number of days in the `date range / interval` can be `> 100`, add

```
  OPTION (MAXRECURSON 0);
```

Comment: What is `n` in this query?